# Creating installable application from Java

Tags: java, install4j

I've been trying to create an installer for a while now, and everything seems to work except adding external `.jar` files. My application imports the `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`, in order to connect to the inbuilt MySql DB, But whenever I try to start the program via launcher (after installing), exceptions are thrown stating the mysql connector driver cannot be found. Would be glad if anyone could tell me the most straight-forward way to include external `.jars` with installer4j

Comment: I would go back to the documentation and have a read of **Step 2: Files**.  This should define the files that need to be added to your distro and where those files should be installed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just solved the problem. It seems that external .jars need to be added individually on Step 3 in the classpath